# MVC 5 Database connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using MVC 5 local database and I get this error trying to run my second custom controller. These are my connection strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MusicDatabase-20160903072514.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MusicDatabase-20160903072514;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="MusicDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

public class MusicDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
}
```

Error:

An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)

Answer (score 0):

According to my opinion if you are using entity framework in your mvc project then that framework automatically creates a connection string in your Web.Config file for its own use and adds a particular name to it.In your case your are missing that particular connection string.I advise you to create your models or database  using entity framework again and check for the connection string